# VBA: Why Does My Range Offset Return 0 (or Empty)?

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, offset

I've been staring at this code for so long, I think I'm missing something very simple. The goal of this statement is to set the "lastRowCompass" variable (range) as the first empty cell in the column:

```
Set lastRowCompass = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

Once the variable is set, I want to use it in a loop like so:

```
For i = lastRowCompass To Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4) <> "" Then
    Cells(i, 4).Offset(0, -2) = hireDate
End If
Next
```

The variable is declared as a Range so this is very confusing. When I step through the code, i = 0 even after executing the set statement. Does anyone have any suggestions? All the examples I've looked at haven't helped me troubleshoot the issue. Many thanks!

EDIT: I've also tried this line:

```
Set lastRowCompass =Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```

and this line:

```
Set lastRowCompass = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```

but I've got the same results with both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `For i =` you must have an integer, but you are passing the Range.
(The Offset returns a Range object, so you lastRowCompass is not an integer, it's a Range)

I think the program cannot convert a Range to an integer exactly the way you like.

Try using `For i = lastRowCompass.Row` or another start value.

---

If I may suggest, always use `Option Explicit` at top of the code file.
That will demand you to declare all variable (little extra coding), but can help avoiding some weird assignments.

Comment: On the money. If you debug `?lastRowCompass` in the Immediate window, you'll see a value of "0", which is the correct "value" for this range variable -- it's an empty cell (and it should be, based on what OP is attempting to do with it).  If this had been anything other than a 1x1 range, it would've thrown a `mismatch` error.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I changed `For i = lastRowCompass` to `For i = lastRowCompass.Row` and it works perfectly! I actually did use `Option Explicit` at the top of my code (it just isn't shown in the example).